# Xcode13 unavailable keys on info.plist

Tags: info.plist, xcode13

### Summary:

I want to know how to add the following snippet to info.plist on Xcode13, when I cannot find the name of keys I want to add in the key name list.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
  <dict>
  <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
  <array>
    <string>fbAPP-ID</string>
  </array>
  </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>APP-ID</string>
<key>FacebookClientToken</key>
<string>CLIENT-TOKEN</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>APP-NAME</string>
```

### Details:

I am working to integrate **FACEBOOK login API** to my application written in **SwiftUI**. However, under the meta developer instructions, we need to add the code in info.plist. As usual, on Custom **IOS target properties** pane (projectname -> target -> info -> Custom IOS target properties), I tried to add the key by the following way :

1. Pushed a plus button;
2. Searched a key name in the appeared list.

However, I cannot find the following keys.

- CFBundleURLSchemes
- CFBundleURLTypes
- FacebookAppID
- FacebookClientToken

I have already completed the forward steps in the instructions.

**My environment:**

- MacOS monterey v12.1
- Xcode Version 13.2.1 (13C100)
- SwiftUI

Answer (score 2):

Search is just for tips, you can add any key you want by copy-paste:

[image: demo]

*btw, URL types are added in section below URL Types:

[image: demo2]

Comment: I appreciate it. I successfully added them.